# Reactjs fetching data from express backend

Tags: reactjs, express

I am currently learning reactjs with expressjs backend.
Currently, i am able to fetch data on page load using componentWillMount();

```
//APP.JS
componentWillMount() {
    fetch('/hotels')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        this.getHotels(result);
      });
}
```

this works fine.

Now i have created a component called topbar, to which basically renders a navigation header (like the one stack overflow or facebook has). in topBar.js, i have:

```
//topbar.js
const topBar = () => {
return(
    <div className="topBar">
        <input type="image" className="logo"  src={logo} onClick = {logoClick} alt = "Trip Advisor"/>
        <button className="buttonStyle" onClick = {hotelsClick}>Hotels</button>
        <button className="buttonStyle" onClick = {vRentalClick}>Vacation Rentals</button>
        <button className="buttonStyle">Flights</button>
        <button className="buttonStyle">Cafés</button>
        <button className="buttonStyle" disabled></button>
        <button className="buttonStyle">My Trips</button>
        <button className="buttonStyle" onClick = {join}>Join</button>
    </div>
)
}
```

On clicking the hotels button, in the hotelsClick function defined in topbar.js file, I want to be able to fetch the '/hotels' (or some other page) from backend, and display it in a div (or just save it in state) in App.js. What would be the correct way to do it?

Comment: Can you post all the relevant code please.

Comment: But I think what you're looking for is react-router.

Comment: If you want to fetch data in App, root component, you should leave the code as is and add to the render() of App component your header and place data inside props and propagate it to header component. Whew.. A lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not prefered or best way to do this, but if you want to try it like this, you get data in App comonent, pass data to toolBar  via props and then you can access data in topBar component. Also event handlers should be passed via props also to call back main method in App.

```
class App extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor() {
      this.state = {data: null};
      this.hotelsClick = this.hotelsClick.bind(this);
    }    
    componentWillMount() {
       // get data, place it in state
       fetch('/hotels')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((result) => {
           this.setState(data:this.getHotels(result));
       });
   }
   hotelsClick() {
      //callback function
   }
   render() {
       const {data} = this.state;
       return(
           <topBar data={data} hotelsClick="this.hotelsClick"  />

        ... etc
       )
    }
};

//topbar.js
const topBar = () => {
    return(
      <div className="topBar">
        <input type="image" className="logo"  src={this.props.data.logo}  />
      <button className="buttonStyle" onClick = {this.props.hotelsClick()}>Hotels</button>
      </div>
      // etc..
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this :)